# Doctrine 2 console commands fail

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm still experiencing issues with the console commands in Doctrine 2.

During first set up of my project I could run the console commands to update the db from my annotated models without a problem e.g.

```
doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

Since then I've been diligently working away on the project and now need to run this again. However, now when the above runs nothing happens. No error message, no report on success - the command just completes silently.

I'm presuming that I've done something that's broken this but I've no way of knowing without some kind of error report so I'm stumped.

How can I work out what the problem is????

Comment: Have you updated the library version by any chance?

Comment: Does a simple `doctrine` give the expected result or is that one also not working?

Comment: No, the library version is unchanged

Comment: `doctrine` by itself lists the help info as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've got this working. Rather foolishly I'd added a class to the models directory that should have been elsewhere and removing this seems to permit the schema-tool to work. It would be nice if the tool gave some feedback though rather than just 'completing' silently, but ultimately just a daft oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have any data fixtures in your DB you could try dropping it and recreating it again.

```
doctrine orm:schema-tool:drop --force  --full-database
doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Personally I manage the updates with the Doctrine migrations tool. I had some issues getting :update to work as expected when I was first trying it out.

Comment: I tried the drop command (without the `--full-database` bit) with the same (non)effect - silent completion and no error or success message. I can't access my machine at the moment but will give the full drop command you mention a go